# ADFS / external login / WsFederation

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation

I am trying to login against ADFS 2016 using WsFederation in a ASP.NET Core Web App / c# . The application is redirecting correct to the to external login page and I am getting redirected back ok. But "GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()” does just return null whatever I do so I am stuck. Is there anyone can help to point out what to change / what I am missing or doing wrong. The relevant code s below.

---

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  String connectionString = GetSqlServerConnectionString();

  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddSession(); // add session

  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


  services.AddAuthentication().AddWsFederation(options =>
  {
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://..removed..";
    options.Wtrealm = "https://..removed..";
    options.Wreply = "https://..removed..";
  });

  services.AddControllersWithViews();
 }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
   app.UseHsts();
  }
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseSession();
   
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
}
```

---

```
public AuthenticationController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
{
  _signInManager = signInManager;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
  var provider = "WsFederation";
  var redirectUrl = "..removed....";
  var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
  return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

---

```
public AdfsCallbackController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
{
  _signInManager = signInManager;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ContentResult> CallbackAsync()
{
  var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            
  if (info == null)
  {
    SLog.AddMessage("AdfsControllers.Post", "info is null", 5);
  }
  else
  {
    SLog.AddMessage("AdfsControllers.Post", info.ToString(), 5);
  }
    return base.Content("Hello", "text/html");
}
```